# Is it better to use $in or $gt, $lt ($gte, $lte)?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Consider a collection with `age` field. The values of `age` are from a known range of `Integer` values.

When querying for users of age 20 to 23 years, the query can be written as:

```
"age": {
    "$gte": 20
    "$lte": 23,
},
```

Since we know the age range, the query can also be written as:

```
"age": {
    "$in": [20,21,22,23]
},
```

Is the query performance better when using `$in` or `$gte`, `$lte`?

Comment: What index do you have in the collection? e.g., what's the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()`?

Comment: How would an `age` index be any different whether `$in` or `$gt, $lt` is used?

Comment: The size of the index, the size of your memory, and how warm the cache is could be the difference. `$in` is like a targeted query, while `$gte` would be a range query. It's more complex once you introduce more fields, but have a look at https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/ for a good explanation on how to optimize index use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's big difference in performance between `$in` and `$gte` when you have small array. Obviously, when you use array with big numbers of elements in `$in` operator, it's better use `$gte`, because mongo does not need to compare a value with every value in array, it's faster just use conditional expression with two values. More over for readability it's better to use `$gte` and `$lte`. So, in common case I'd use `$gte` and `$lte`.

Comment: Funny enough, for age values 19-99 the $in query seems to have a faster execution time than the $gte, $lte query in my tests with mongodb profiler.

Comment: I think $gte/$lte gets converted into a range query, and $in does a mini-fanout. As $in gets larger, I'd expect $gte/$lte to start beating it. You should be able to see the different query plans if you do an explain.